# Let $f: \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$. Find $f((0,2))$.

Tags: functions

So for the question I know it's asking for the interval of the codomain that corresponds to the interval $(0,2)$ of the domain. I know that the upper part of the interval is $(y,2.5)$ but I don't know what $y$ would be. Since $0$ is not even in the domain of $f$, could $y$ be the empty set? This does not seem right to me though. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $(0,2)$ is an open interval, so that the function is well defined on it, since $0$ doesn't belong to this interval. Try computing the limit for $x\to 0$.

Comment: Doesn't the limit for x→0 not exist though?

Comment: The limit is $\infty$

Comment: You are right, this limit doesn't exist, I meant $x\to0^{+}$ (converging to $0$ with $x>0$).

Comment: I tried taking the limit into consideration but it doesn't exist at 0.

Comment: The limit doesn't exist because while $x\to 0$ with $x>0$, it converges to $\infty$ and with $x<0$, it converges to $-infty$. It tells us that if you take a very small positive value for $x$, you will get a very large value for $f(x)$, which translates the idea of the limit $x\to 0^{+}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, find $f(x)$ at the boundaries.

At the lower bound $x = 0$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \left(x + \frac{1}{x} \right)= \infty $$

At the upper bound $x = 2$
$$ \lim_{x\to 2^-} \left(x + \frac{1}{x} \right)= \infty = 2.5 $$

Second, check to see if the function has any local minima or maxima
$$ f'(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{x^2-1}{x^2}$$

$ f'(x) = 0$ if $x = \pm 1$. One of these points, $x = 1$, lies within the interval of consideration. This is a local minimum as the function is very large and positive near $0^+$. This minimum value is $f(1) = 2$

To conclude, we found that $2 \le f(x) < \infty$ in $(0,2)$, so the codomain is $[2, \infty)$

Comment: This makes sense, thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help! Please mark an answer as best answer to close the question.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: $(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1\geq 0$. What does this imply about 
$$
x+\frac{1}{x}
$$
?

Comment: Could you explain where you got $(x-1)^2$ from?

Comment: @Robin Note $x+\frac{1}{x}=\frac{x^2+1}{x}$. The idea is to find a way to bound this by below. This is where my hint comes in